# How to output multiple plots in J?

Tags: j

In J programming, I had several lines of plot codes, either plot or pd 'show', but the output is only the last plot. How should I solve this? Thank you!

x =: 1 2 3 4 5 6
y =: 2 3 4 5 6 7

z =: 4 6 7 9 5 3

I know putting both into one graph is like x;y,:z

But I want to output two plots like:
plot1 is x;y
plot2 is x;z

But everytime I run the code, I only got x;z shown

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the part of code that causes you issues.

Comment: Hi cid, I edited my post thanks!

Comment: Adding all plots with pd data, then, at the end, using pd show, will also show all plots.

Comment: But when I used pd, it will show on the same plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that the plot window is being reused. I think that this is intentional to relieve the user from having to clean up each plot that is created after it has been viewed.

The way around this is to use the object oriented aspect of J so that each window is treated as a separate object. Ric Sherlock gives a good description of this at https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Plot/Class , but try the following answer to see if it works for you.

```
   x =: 1 2 3 4 5 6
   y =: 2 3 4 5 6 7
   z =: 4 6 7 9 5 3

   a=: conew 'jzplot'
   b=: conew 'jzplot'
   plot__a x;z
   plot__b x;y
```

and after you have closed the windows, clear out the locales which support the objects with

```
   codestroy__a ''
1
   codestroy__b ''
1
```

Object oriented programming is covered well in the labs in J and if you are not familiar with it, it would be worth a look to understand the technical details of the above code.

Comment: Happy to help out! You might give the answer a click on the up arrow, as this gives a clearer signal that the answer has been accepted by the questioner than a mention in the comments. :-)

Comment: Done. First time user. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: No worries, enjoy the ride!